# What is the orchestral music from the start of Top Gear special "The Worst Car in the World"?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

What is the orchestral music from about the first 15 seconds of the [Top Gear special "The Worst Car in the World"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2540072/)?

You can hear (and watch) it [here](https://youtu.be/43CNoe0hhMM), though the video may be removed soon.

I want to say it's a theme to a movie but I'm not certain. It may have been made specifically for Top Gear.

Comment: i used shazam. shazam says it is "invincible" from "james brett". i remember i also searched this music 1-2 years ago. and i never find any clue about this music.but  this time i found few things there is a composer called "james seymour brett" he also composing similar music. but i cant find any sample for this music. perhaps because copyrights held by some movie studios. and they didnt want sharing info. i found some sites says "james brett - invincible" 30 seconds in length. perhaps this music only composed 30 seconds to use in a intro. i wish i can remember where i first heard this music.

Comment: You've got the answer I think.  There are [some posts on Reddit](https://forums.finalgear.com/top-gear-2002-2015/the-worst-car-in-the-history-of-the-world-song-list-56921/)  suggesting that the Top Gear series uses a lot of music from "Extreme Music", and sure enough, on the Exterme Music website on this album "Epic Adventure" (DCD017)  by James Brett, there is the track you mention, [track 16 Invincible](https://www.extrememusic.com/albums/1321)

Comment: @Angst, I recommend you post an answer :)

Comment: @hfc, go ahead and answer, as you found it first.

Comment: @Angst i could answer but you are the one who found full and original version of this song. i think you should answer for your effort on more detailed and precise information. and i have to mention, according to original album it seems original song is only 35 seconds. and there is a 30 second demo version.

Answer (score 2):

Music is "Invincible" by James Brett. [Thanks to @hfc for first identifying using Shazam]. There are some [Reddit posts about Top Gear](https://forums.finalgear.com/top-gear-2002-2015/the-worst-car-in-the-history-of-the-world-song-list-56921/) suggesting that the Top Gear series uses a lot of music from a company called "Extreme Music". Some searching in the Extreme Music website found [album "Epic Adventure" (DCD017)](https://www.extrememusic.com/albums/1321) by James Brett, and "Invincible" is track 16 (full version 35s). Without the Reddit posts, giving some background info, it would not have been possible to confirm the piece, as there are many many companies that sell music for TV shows/games/etc - worth noting for other questions like this...